# Injecting code into Cocoa applications after they are running, is it possible?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Apple's WebView and WKWebView assume that you want to share cookies with Safari and for the application that I'm building, I really don't want that. Unfortunately, they just use a singleton NSHTTPCookieStorage that you have no access to and that's it.

I been thinking of writing a library that redefines parts of NSHTTPCookieStorage and use DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES to load it before hand, so that I could read and write cookies from a different location. Unfortunately, part of our application is a screensaver, which is not an application but a library (like a plug in) that gets loaded by the screen saver app, so by the time I get control, it's too late to use DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES.

Are there any other ways of achieving this? Of modifying a class that is already loaded?

Comment: Have you read Mike Solomon's ["Cocoa Reverse Engineering" essay](http://code.google.com/p/simbl/wiki/CocoaReverseEngineering)?

Comment: @JoshCaswell no, but I'm going to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. Objective-C runtime has some kind of a table which maps the `selector name` to `selector implementation`, and you can edit this table at run time.

You may want to check out [this library](https://github.com/rentzsch/jrswizzle)

Answer (score 1):

You could try **dyld-interposing**

See dyld-interposing.h:
http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-97.1/include/mach-o/dyld-interposing.h

This comment:
https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-01-30-code-injection.html#comment-3fb6e4b8cf65ec984e7836e2b86a2875